# Applying x:key and x:Name

Tags: wpf, windows, xaml, windows-phone

I am new to windows phone programming.Please apologize if the question is too basic.

Can anyone say in what situation I should use x:Key element and x:Name element?

What might be the difference of the two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 x:Key
```

Is used when you need to define an element in a ResourceDictionary .

For example : a Style or some element you wan't to initalize in xaml .

```
    <Style TargetType=Button x:Key="MyBtnStyle>
            ......

    <myLocalNs:MyType x:Key="MyType1" />
```

.

```
 x:Name
```

Would be used when you wan't to eather reference an element from Your Code Behind :

```
 <UserControl>
    <Grid x:Name="grid">
        <Button x:Name="btn" />
    </Grid>
 </UserControl>
```

in the UserControl.cs :

```
     btn.Contnent = "Im A Button";
     grid.RowDefenitions.Add(new RowDefenition());
```

another case where you would use x:Name is when targeting an element in a ControlTemplate / DataTemplate / Style through Triggers , using **TargetName**

For Example :

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type h:HierarchicalNode}">     
        <Grid>                              
            <CheckBox  x:Name="chkbox" />
        </Grid>     
   <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasChildren}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="chkbox"/>
        </DataTrigger>        
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Another case is when you would wan't to bind to an element in XAML .

```
 <UserControl>
    <Grid x:Name="grid">
        <Button x:Name="btn" Content="{Binding ElementName=grid ,Path=Name}"/>
    </Grid>
 </UserControl>
```

FYI , x:Name would also be used when you want to Target elements using Interaction Triggers or VisualState's .